# How to backup certain tables in oracle?

Tags: oracle-10g

I want to continue working on oracle db from home and I need certain tables I created. How do I back them up then restore them?

Comment: We're going to need more information. Do you want to transfer the tables electronically? What are your home and not-home environments like? Does the home copy need to be synced back in with the not-home copy?

Comment: I'd suggest asking on serverfault.com

Comment: You probably just need to use the export tool from the command line. But you need to read the manual on this as it's not 100% export and then import at home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely agree with Sathya.  One thing to note -- rather than reading the manual, you can issue "help=Y" to the imp/exp command.  To wit:

```
exp help=y
imp help=y
```

This will show you the most common parameters you can use, and also show you the default values for each parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Quick & easy way - use Oracle's `exp`  & `imp` tools

To export them:

```
exp scott/tiger file=emp.dmp tables=(emp,dept)
```

Transfer the dmp file to your destination & then to import them:

```
imp scott/tiger file=emp.dmp fromuser=scott touser=scott tables=(emp,dept)
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember a tool called ODUMP when I was using Oracle 8i on NetWare.  The following web page explains how to import and export data:  http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ

These import and export tools can be used to transfer an entire database or specific tables, but I believe there is a limitation in that the data has to be imported back to the same tablespace (which won't be a problem if you're using Oracle 10g or newer which have support for tablespace renaming).

I'm not seeing any helpful information for the ODUMP command in Google Search results, so I may not be remembering the name of the tool correctly (I haven't used Oracle for quite a few years now since switching to PostgreSQL, but I still regard it as an excellent SQL server).

Comment: *there is a limitation in that the data has to be imported back to the same tablespace* there's no such limitation - atleast not on "regular" tables. It will cause a problem on Partitioned Tables.

Answer (score 0):

For exporting a table:-

`expdp mydbusername/mydbpassword@mydbinstancename tables=mytablename directory=MY_DIR dumpfile=mytablename.dmp`

For importing a table:-

`impdp mydbusername/mydbpassword@mydbinstancename tables=mytablename directory=MY_DIR dumpfile=mytablename.dmp`

For `directory` parameter you can use default directory `DATA_PUMP_DIR` or you can use your own directory `MY_DIR`.

Oracle version used for above commands:-

`Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit`

Answer (score 0):

To [backup a table in oracle](https://www.oraask.com/2021/08/backup-a-table-in-oracle.html) you can use EXP command ex :

```
exp tables=EMPLOYEES,DEPARTMENTS file=EMP_DEPT_BKP14082021.dmp
```